# How can I place go-template actions with multi-line output at any indentation level?

Tags: go-templates

We're creating yaml using go-templates. In them, we have actions with multi-line output that need to be indented at specific indent level. We can use the `indent` function for this, but it doesn't treat the first line differently and therefor requires the action definition have no indentation level.

For example:

```
foo:
  bar:
    baz:
{{ myYamlOutputtingAction | indent 6 }} # <-- notice 0 indent level
```

Is there a way I can place my action definitions at an indentation level that makes sense for the context of the template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE: sprig `2.13.0+`

Just `nindent` instead of `indent`. The [sprig library](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) includes this function for exactly this use case.

The same code from above can be written as:

```
foo:
  bar:
    baz:
      {{ myYamlOutputtingAction | nindent 6 }}
```

### Old answer for sprig versions before `2.13.0`

You can change this:

```
foo:
  bar:
    baz:
{{ myYamlOutputtingAction | indent 6 }} # <-- notice 0 indent level
```

To this:

```
foo:
  bar:
    baz:
      {{- "\n"}}{{ myYamlOutputtingAction | indent 6 }} # <-- properly indented with a little bit fluff
```

---

**A little explanation**

This works by ensuring whatever content follows the `{{- "\n"}}` has 0 indentation. This means you can trade a hacky `{{- "\n"}}` for proper indentation whenever it makes sense. We generally think it's worth it.

Comment: I suppose you could also do `baz:{{"\n"}}{{ action | indent 11 }}`

Comment: you have a typo on your code sample. it should be `{{- "\n"}}{{...` instead of `{{- "\n"}{{...`